# Request interceptors not modifying the value of request header in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I am using `http-proxy-middleware` to create a proxy and it's running successfully.
Before calling `app.use('/',proxy_options);`
I am trying to intercept my request and modifying the request header but updated value is not reflecting in headers.

```
app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
const token=getToken();
req.header['authorization']=token;
next();
});
```

Even I tried with `req.header.authorization=token;` and also without `next();`.
When I am trying to print the my request header `authorization:''` is coming as blank.
Can any one let me know why this happening and how I can resolve this.

Any help or suggestions must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `getToken()` function is fetching token from other apis, then you should add `await` in front of it.

Try to use below code,

```
app.use('/', async (req,res,next)=>{
const token=await getToken();
req.headers['authorization']=token;
next();
});
```

You also need to replace `header` by `headers`, as mentioned above in code snippet.

It should work.

Comment: It didn't worked.after setting the Authorization values I just print the headers in console but it's coming with blank

Comment: @Zia, can you please share code snippet of how you are setting the authorization value.